# New tag: [developer-certificate-of-origin]

Tags: discussion, tags

The [Developer Certificate of Origin](https://developercertificate.org) is a well-known (citation needed :D) mechanism, used when you need extra reassurance that contributions to a project are permitted. Unfortunately, some of the implementation details are not well-documented. Well, I couldn't find them and I've posted a few questions about it.

I think it's a worthy topic for contribution-oriented Q&A. Can we have a [developer-certificate-of-origin] tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone with 150 rep or more (including you!) can create a new tag - simply enter the new tag when you create or edit a question, and it will be created. You can then edit it to add some description and tag wiki.

See [the privilege's description in the help center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) for more information.

Comment: I was wearing ruby slippers all along :D thanks!

Comment: +1 on the Wizard of Oz reference